# How To Automate Vertical Column Borders for 2Column-Groups

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an automated-process that adds  **bold** **VERTICAL** borders for TWO-PAIRED Column Groups.

Tried with fill series and Trend because I do not know how to write it as vba code..

[The end-result should look like the example below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbvS0.jpg)

Need this for my workplace, any advice could help, thank you.

Best Regards,
 Emanuel

Comment: Would it work to use conditional formatting? I'm pretty sure it would be possible to use an equation to determine if the column is an even, and if so add a border on the right....  Although, if a column is added or removed, the lines will remain on every other, not shift with the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional formatting for this, for example:

- Hightlight whole sheet:

[image]

- Go to Conditonal Formatting > New Rule > Use Formula: `=MOD(COLUMN()/2,1)=0`
- Format to your liking, example below:

[image]

It just won't be bold

Comment: If the OP's not used to custom conditional formatting rules, after selecting a generic new rule, they need to set the rule type as formula-based to have the equation-box available.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am currently trying to accomplish it with the conditional-formatting but it returns me the error "You've entered too few arguments for this function'.

Comment: In parallel with // =MOD(COLUMN()/2,1)=0 //  formula, I am also trying the vba code with no luck but I know I'm doing something wrong..

Comment: I will set the correct answer as soon as I manage to do this little conditional formatting rule, Thank you for your time

Comment: @JvdV, I know, it's a problem on my part, I tried doing it as you said but when I'm in the new rule tab, after I insert the =MOD(COLUMN()/2,1)=0 rule this is what happens https://imgur.com/xE6gJ8A

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm doing something wrong, I'm a newbie in the vba-excel domain. Ps: I know I'm doing something wrong .. haha :)

Comment: You probably want to start with selecting the whole sheet as I explained, next you might want to try change `,` into `;`. Maybe your system works with other seperators.

Comment: I started doing it with the whole sheet selected, but after a few trial&errors tried as shown in the print-screen.. Changed , to ; still nothing. But no worries I never give up, Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Try the formula in a random cell and evaluate it, so you understand what it does

Answer (score 0):

Youc could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long

    'Set up to which line to add border
    Lastrow = 10

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Set from which column to begin & end
        For i = 2 To 10 Step 2
            With .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(Lastrow, i)).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: if it works I'll mark it as a correct answer until Tuesday.. don't ask why :) haha Thank you!